# Importing .ics files into Amazon WorkMail - AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, exchange, calendar

I've set up my own work-mail account a while ago (with custom domain etc.) and now I want to migrate all my appointments (including contacts if possible) from my personal google-calendar app to the work-mail exchange .

As I couldn't find a way to migrate the google-calendar data to the aws-exchange *directly* (via the calendar app / dashboard or via gmail - there are only options to sync data **from** third party calendars, not in the other direction) I downloaded all my calenader-data as `.ics` file from google-calendar's [settings/export](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/export)-option but now I can't find a way to import these into my workmail exchange...

AWS tells me that workmail [has great compatibility with outlook and much more](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/features/) which seems to be a bit odd considering that I can't find a way to simply import a `.ics` file.

I'm aware of paid solutions such as [audriga](https://workmail.audriga.com/#start) or [transend](https://www.transend.com/) (both mentioned by aws) but I don't want to pay just for importing or migrating data.

Am I missing something? Or is there really no way to import such things?

*Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws) send me here.*

Comment: You can configure your email account on Outlook desktop client and import .ics to it: File > Open & Export > Import/Export. > Import an iCalendar(.ics) or vCalendar file(.vcs).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aidans [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1531813/importing-ics-files-into-amazon-workmail-aws#comment2323749_1531813)!

It's actually possible by logging into outlook with your email-credentials and importing your `.ics` file over `File > Open & Export > Import / Export > Import .ics ...`

Afterwards the events should pop-up in your outlook app and, if connected to gmail, in your google calendar app.